# Second Slide fullPage.js not shown on chrome

Tags: fullpage.js

I have strange behavior happened on my second slide fullPage.js and so on, the background image is not shown only on chrome web browser but for Opera and Firefox it's no problem.

In first page on every section, the background image is shown no problem on all browser including chrome, but it not shown for second,third page and so on.

Please help me.

```
<div id="fullpage">
   <div class="section " id="section0"> 
        <img class="logo" >
        <h2>My Logo is here</h2>
   </div>

   <div class="section moveDown" id="section1">
       <div class="slide" id="slide1">
           <div class="wrap">
                <div class="box-bg-dark-left-sm box-bg-dark-left-md box-bg-dark-left-lg">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum...</h2>
                Dolor sit amit...   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="box-bg-dark-right-sm box-bg-dark-right-md box-bg-dark-right-lg">
                <h2>Second slide...</h2>
                Blah...
            </div>
        </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* Defining each section background and styles
 * --------------------------------------- */
#section0{
  background-image: url(../imgs/home_large.jpg);
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

img.logo {
  content:url(../imgs/logo_large.png);
}

img.logo:after {
   content:url(../imgs/logo_large.png);
}

#slide1{
   background-image: url(../imgs/pusing_large.jpg);
   padding: 6% 0 0 0;
   background-color: #000;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
#slide2{
   background-image: url(../imgs/many_version_large.jpg);
   padding: 6% 0 0 0;
   background-color: #888;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Provide a reproduction of your problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/418/) or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting the backgrounds is far from normal:

```
img.logo {
  content:url(../imgs/logo_large.png);
}
```

Please take a look at [this demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html) and its [source code](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/backgrounds.html) available in the fullpage.js files.

You'll see the way of using a background is by using the `background` property:

```
#section0{
    background-image: url(imgs/bg1.jpg);
    padding: 30% 0 0 0;
}
```

Also, regarding your second slide, probably its because you are using a fixed positioned background.

Just remove this line from `#slide2`

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```